# Selenium, Unable to get all data from certain pages

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to extract the source page from the following website:

http://www.lewisbrisbois.com

with Selenium/Firefox.  I am not familiar with this problem, and have never seen it before, but Selenium only gives me a very small amount of source code (far less than what is visibile in the browser).

Comment: Well what code are you using? What version of Selenium? What version of Firefox? What output *does* it give?

Comment: The code is not being loaded after the page does is it? Javascript etc..

Answer (score 0):

The (erroneous) source code my browser loads is this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>LEWISBRISBOIS.COM</title>
        <meta name="keywords" content=""
    </head>
    <frameset rows="100%", *" border="0" frameborder="0">
        <frame src="http://www.lbbslaw.com" name="LEWISBRISBOIS.COM">
    </frameset>
</html>
```

Try to directly access http://www.lbbslaw.com/ in your Selenium code, that will probably give you what you expect.